# How to use Evaluation Monitor in conjunction with NonlineaModelFit?

Tags: numerics, fitting

I am trying to find out how many function, gradient and hessian evaluations are made when i run NonlinearModelFit for example in this case

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x, Method-> "Newton"]
```

So far i have only managed to know, what i assume are, the function evaluations

```
Block[{c = 0}, {nlm = 
NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x, 
Method -> "Newton", EvaluationMonitor :> c++], c}]
```

Thanks

Comment: Trace[nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x, Method-> "Newton"],Log[__]]

Comment: Take a look at the `FindMinimum` documentation on how to use `EvaluationMonitor` and `StepMonitor`. Also look at the tutorial on unconstrained and constrained optimization (Tutorials at top of relevant doc pages) and the FindMinimumPlot functions from ExtraPackages -> Optimization -> UnconstrainedProblems.m (this is used in the tutorials).

Answer (score 4):

Following [Szabolcs advice](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91527/how-to-use-evaluation-monitor-in-conjunction-with-nonlineamodelfit#comment248622_91527), it seems that the [Documentation page for `EvaluationMonitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html) contains all what you need for `Method -> "Newton"`:

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};

Clear[evalCount];
evalCount[_] = 0;
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x, 
   EvaluationMonitor :> ++evalCount["Function"], 
   Gradient -> {"Symbolic", EvaluationMonitor :> ++evalCount["Gradient"]}, 
   Method -> {"Newton", 
     "Hessian" -> {"Symbolic", EvaluationMonitor :> ++evalCount["Hessian"]}}];
TableForm[evalCount /@ #, TableHeadings -> {#, None}] &@{"Function", "Gradient", 
  "Hessian"}
```

> [image: table]

Other `Method`s take different suboptions, for example `"LevenbergMarquardt"`:

```
Clear[evalCount];
evalCount[_] = 0;
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x, 
   EvaluationMonitor :> ++evalCount["Function"], 
   Gradient -> {"Symbolic", EvaluationMonitor :> ++evalCount["Gradient"]}, 
   Method -> {"LevenbergMarquardt", 
     "Residual" -> {"Symbolic", EvaluationMonitor :> ++evalCount["Residual"]}, 
     "Jacobian" -> {"Symbolic", EvaluationMonitor :> ++evalCount["Jacobian"]}}];
TableForm[evalCount /@ #, TableHeadings -> {#, None}] &@{"Function", "Gradient", 
  "Residual", "Jacobian"}
```

> [image: table]

Although I'm not sure why inside of `Method` suboptions `EvaluationMonitor` does not catch anything for `NonlinearModelFit`...

Answer (score 2):

So following @Szabolcs advice,

```
 {nl,ncounts}=Block[{c = 0}, {NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x, 
    Method -> "Newton", EvaluationMonitor :> c++], c}]
```

or  (doing something slightly different) counting the number of `Log` Calls.

```
  Trace[nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x, 
   Method-> "Newton"],Log[__]]//Flatten//Length
```

but it seems you have changed your question…